# Получение ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется ссылка такого вида:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="window.location.href='/cat/link'" id="next">Следующий</a>
```

Как извлечь из неё путь к следующей странице?

Например, из обычной ссылки мы получаем его вот так:

```
$('#next').attr('href')
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#next').attr('onclick').split("'")[1]
```

Но рекомендуется в таких случаях дублировать ссылку в аттрибут href, тогда будет:

```
<a href="/cat/link" onclick="event.preventDefault();window.location.href='/cat/link'" id="next">Следующий</a>
```

Не требуется костыликов, seo работает.

Comment: Код генерируется системой, поэтому добавить ссылку в href нет возможности. Но, решение рабочее. Спасибо.